# Asterisk with BLINK: setting up tls connection

Tags: ssl, asterisk, sip, fedora

Im trying to setup secure voip connexion with tls using Asterisk server and Blink as client (configured as mentioned in this [tutorial](https://www.networklab.fr/chiffrement-des-appels/)). More details are below:

> sip.conf:

```
[general]
bindaddr=0.0.0.0
deny=all
allow=ulaw
allow=gsm

tlsenable=yes
tlsbindaddr=0.0.0.0
tlscertfile=/etc/asterisk/keys/asterisk.pem
tlscafile=/etc/asterisk/keys/ca.crt
tlscapath=/etc/asterisk/keys
tlsprivatekey=/etc/asterisk/keys/asterisk.key
tlscipher=ALL
tlsclientmethod=tlsv1
encryption=yes

[5001]
type=friend
host=dynamic
context=phones
secret=5001
username=yassine
transport=tls
dtmfmode=rfc2833
port=5061
```

On client registration, Asterisk CLI give this message:

> **tcptls.c:644 handle_tcptls_connection:** Problem setting up ssl connection: error:000000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)
>
> **tcptls.c:730 handle_tcptls_connection:** FILE * open failed!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since error is indicating problem with opening file - you have to check that all files added to configuration exist and user running the program has permissions to read them

Comment: Hi  Artemy, thanks for your comment but all files exist with 777 permissions.

Comment: I see same problem reported at different forum. As last post in the thread specifies - they have repeated the key generation using slightly different procedure - and succeed to connect using one of the clients. So maybe you can also repeat the key generation and see if it makes a difference. http://asteriskforum.ru/viewtopic.php?t=7404 (post in Russian but last reply contains all the steps)

Comment: Thanks  Artemy Vysotsky, all done with success! :)